# Registering and showing data in select

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try the "hentmekanikersel" function which is trying to bring firstname and surname into a select element which is in my html, I don't think it knows what database I need the data from so how do I make it work?

What the whole code is about is registering a kunde and a mekaniker and then registering a time for them to meet.

A kunde is a customer in Norwegian and mekaniker is a mechanic.

```js
 var inpmekfornavn = document.getElementById("inpmekfornavn");
 var inpmeketternavn = document.getElementById("inpmeketternavn");

 var inpkfornavn = document.getElementById("inpkfornavn");
 var inpketternavn = document.getElementById("inpketternavn");
 var inpadresse = document.getElementById("inpadresse");
 var inpmobil = document.getElementById("inpmobil");
 var inppoststed = document.getElementById("inppoststed");
 var inppostnr = document.getElementById("inppostnr");
 var inpepost = document.getElementById("inpepost");

 var inpmekaniker = document.getElementById("inpmekaniker");
 var inpkunde = document.getElementById("inpkunde");
 var inpdato = document.getElementById("inpdato");
 var inptidspunkt = document.getElementById("inptidspunkt");

 var database = firebase.database();
 var mekaniker = database.ref("mekaniker");
 var kunde = database.ref("kunde");
  
  
//trying to get data from database"mekaniker" into a select
 function hentmekanikersel(snapshot){
  var mekselkey = snapshot.key;
  var mekselinfo = snapshot.val();
  var mekselref = database.ref("mekaniker")

  inpmekaniker.innerHTML += `
   <option value="${mekselkey}">${mekselinfo}</option>
  `
 }


 function hentkunde(snapshot){
  
 }

 function registrermekaniker(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  //henter ut verdiene til mekaniker
  var fornavn = inpmekfornavn.value;
  var etternavn = inpmeketternavn.value;

  //nullstiller verdiene til inputfeltene
  inpmekfornavn = "";
  inpmeketternavn = "";

  //registrer mekaniker I databasen
  mekaniker.push({
   "fornavn" : fornavn,
   "etternavn" : etternavn
  });
 }
 skjema.onsubmit = registrermekaniker;

 function registrerkunde(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var Fornavn = inpkfornavn.value;
  var Etternavn = inpketternavn.value;
  var Adresse = inpadresse.value;
  var Poststed = inppoststed.value;
  var Postnr = inppostnr.value;
  var Mobil = inpmobil.value;
  var Epost = inpepost.value;

  inpkfornavn = "";
  inpketternavn = "";
  inpadresse = "";
  inppoststed = "";
  inppostnr = "";
  inpmobil = "";
  inpepost = "";

  kunde.push({
   "Fornavn" : Fornavn,
   "Etternavn" : Etternavn,
   "Adresse" : Adresse,
   "Poststed" : Poststed,
   "Postnr" : Postnr,
   "Mobil" : Mobil,
   "Epost" : Epost
  })
 }
 skjema2.onsubmit = registrerkunde;
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-small;
}

.label {
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
}

input[type=text] {
    display: block;
    width: 98.5%;
    height:;
    font-size: inherit;
}

select {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5em;
    font-size: 10px;
}
button {
    display: block;
    font-size: inherit;
}

table {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;

}

th {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    background: blue;
}

div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBpDL_l4TEIidZ2gSLb6uLXY44IObWnBEM",
    authDomain: "khra-89294.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://khra-89294.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "khra-89294",
    storageBucket: "khra-89294.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1063667109904"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

 <center>
<h1>Kulbil</h1>
</center>
<center>
<div>
<!-- A form for Arrangement-->
<h3>register Mekaniker:</h3>
<h3>Register Kunde:</h3>
<form id="skjema">
        <label class="label">Fornavn: <input id="inpmekfornavn" type="text"></label>
        <label class="label">Etternavn:<input id="inpmeketternavn"type="text"></label>
        <button type="submit">Send inn</button>
</form>

<form id="skjema2">
    <label class="label">Fornavn: <input id="inpkfornavn" type="text"></label>
    <label class="label">Etternavn: <input id="inpketternavn" type="text"></label>
    <label class="label">Adresse: <input id="inpadresse" type="text"></label>
    <label class="label">Mobilnr: <input id="inpmobil" type="text"></label>
    <label class="label">Poststed: <input id="inppoststed"type="text"></label>
    <label class="label">Postnr: <input id="inppostnr"type="text"></label>
    <label class="label">E-post: <input id="inpepost"type="text"></label>
    <button type="submit">Send inn</button>
</form>

    <form id="skjema3">
  <label class="label">Velg Mekaniker<select id="inpmekaniker"></select></label>
  <label class="label">Velg Kunde<select id="inpkunde"></select></label>
  <label class="label"><input id="inpdato" type="text" placeholder="01.01.2000"></label>
  <label class="label"><input id="inptidspunkt" type="text" placeholder="13.45"></label> 
 </form>
</div>
</center>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<table>
    <tr><th>Fornavn</th><th>Etternavn:</th><th>Adresse:</th><th>Mobilnummer:</th><th>Poststed:</th></tr>
    <tbody id="txttabell"></tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table>
    <tr><th>Kundens fornavn:</th><th>kundens etternavn:</th><th>Mekaniker fornavn:</th><th>Mekaniker etternavn:</th><th>Dato:</th><th>Tidspunkt:</th></tr>
    <tbody id="txttabell2"></tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```